# Cron Job timeout: PHP script to download long videos

Tags: php

I call the script `mywebsite.com/download.php` in crontab.

download.php

```
$video_url = "www.example.com/sample.mp4";  //hour long video
$link = '/home/mywebsite.com/videos/test.mp4';

$chunkSize = 1;
$chunksize = $chunkSize*(1024*1024); // How many bytes per chunk
$data = '';
$bytesCount = 0;
$handle = fopen($video_url, 'rb');
$fp = fopen($link, 'w');
if ($handle === false) {
    return false;
}
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $data = fread($handle, $chunksize);
    fwrite($fp, $data, strlen($data));
}
$status = fclose($handle);
fclose($fp);
```

The problem is the script timeouts with long videos.  I don't have the option of increasing server timeout limits.

What is an alternate method to guarantee the video get's downloaded?

`ignore_user_abort();` ?

`set_time_limit(0);` ?  Will this be ignored by server?

I have a queue system so only 1 video downloads at a time.

crontab call
`*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/example.com/index.php media get_video`

Comment: Crontab is CLI and it's timeout is hardcoded to be 0. Contact server administrator to know if it's somehow limited.

Comment: Not if the crontab is called in the context of a web request, that happens from one service provider to another.

Comment: Show us the call from the crontab file.

Comment: @paskl check edit

Comment: Are you sure 15 minutes is enough to download that big file? And no two cron jobs happen to write to the same file the same content at the same time?

Comment: i have a queue system.  if the file hasn't finished downloaded the next 15 minutes, the script won't run and the file will continue to download.

Comment: There are several potential bugs in your code as well `if($handle===false)` doesn't close the `$fp` pointer, the `$fp` pointer is never checked if the file opens, `fread` isn't being checked (ie `$data` may be `false`, not a number  - which can happen if the url breaks!) and so on.

Comment: Also, I'd typically recommend using PHP's `curl` library instead of `fread`/`fwrite`, as I typically disable remote/http reads in my php.ini config for security reasons.  I've found `curl` handles better, and gives more/better debugging information (did the link break? did the server respond with an error code? can I re-initiate the connection? etc....)

Comment: Why are you using PHP at all? Just put a call to `curl` or `wget` in your crontab.